# Range of doubles in Swift

Tags: xcode, double, swift, addition

I am currently writing a Swift application and parts of it require making sure certain user inputs add up to a specified value.

A simplified example:

Through program interaction, the user has specified that totalValue = 67 and that turns = 2. This means that in two inputs, the user will have to provide two values that add up to 67.

So lets say on turn 1 the user enters 32, and then on turn 2 he enters 35, this would be valid because 32 + 35 = 67.

This all works fine, but the moment we verge into more than one decimal place, the program cannot add the numbers correctly. For example, if totalValue = 67 and then on turn 1 the user enters 66.95 and then on turn 2 he enters .05 the program will return that this is an error despite the fact that 
66.95 + .05 = 67. This problem does not happen with one decimal place or less (something like turn 1 = 55.5 and turn 2 = 11.5 works fine), only for two decimal spots and beyond. I am storing the values as doubles. Thanks in advance

Some example code:

```
var totalWeights = 67
var input = Double(myTextField.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().doubleValue)

/*Each turn is for a button click*/

/*For turn 1*/
if inputValid == true && turn == 1 && input < totalWeights
{

  myArray[0] = input  

}
else
{
//show error string
}

/*For turn 2*/
if inputValid == true && turn == 2 && input == (totalWeights - myArray[0])
{

 myArray[1] = input

}
else
{

//show error string

}
```

Comment: Show some code on how you are doing this, as I don't see how looping through an array of values could lead to this problem.

Comment: You must specify the type by writing it after the variable, separated by a colon example: let myDoubleValue: Double = 70 instead of let myDoubleValue = 70.0

Comment: Doesn't swift assume types?

Comment: @eddwinpaz `let myDoubleValue = 70.0` is same as `let myDoubleValue: Double = 70`, `70.0` is `Double` by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no ideal solution to this. We must use approximation type comparison.

For example, instead of checking:

```
if val1 == val2
```

we must try something like:

```
if val1 > (val2 - .0005) && val1 < (val2 + .0005)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It is actually true. I would only add that it's because we are working with floating point numbers. And I would probably take something less than `0.0005`, closer to the [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). I don't know what the machine epsilon in this case is, but I guess it's not `0.0005`.

Comment: This is a pretty naive approach to solving the problem.  Given that he's using swift, using NSDecimalNumber is the (more) correct answer.

Comment: There's nothing naive about this approach.  It's a basic technique for comparing two floating point numbers, although I would go with a more readable version e.g. `fabs(val1 - val2) < 0.0005`

Comment: No, this is naive. `Float`/`Double` is the *wrong* type for dealing with *exact* floating point computations, you should use them only if you're dealing with _approximate_ values. `NSDecimalNumber` is the right type to use for that. It is true that using an error is the right way to compare floating point values, but these shouldn't be floating point values at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you want exact values from floating point then the float/double types will not work, as they are only ever approximations of exact numbers.  Look into using the NSDecimalNumber class from within Swift, I'm not sure what the bridging would look like but it should be simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how this could work:

```
var a = 0
for num in numlist {
    a += num
}
var result = false
if a == targetnum
  result = true
```

I haven't tested this out, but if `numlist` is an array of double then it should work for any input that is a valid number.

One problem I just realized is that there is an issue with doing an equals with doubles, as rounding will cause problems for you.  I am not going to show it, but if, while reading in the inputs you keep track of how many numbers to the right of the decimal place, then multiply all of the values by that number of tens, so `66.95 * 100` to get it all as an integer, then add, then do the comparison, after multiplying the targetnum by the same value (100).

Comment: I tried this by making functions which take in the values and multiply by 1000 then compare, but no luck

Comment: The problem is that if totalValue = 50, and my two turns are 49.95 and .05 respectively the program will evaluate totalValue - myArray[0] to a value like 49.99999999997 instead of 50 so even converting to ints and multiplying by 1000 will create a comparison of 5000 == 4999 which evaluates to false

Comment: Convert to an int before doing anything else.  So 49.95 is 4950 and .05 is 5, then do the math and compare